# I cannot instal any package on Atom (Win x64)

Tags: installation, package, atom-editor

When I try to install any package it tells me `certificate has expired`, and when it tries to load the Featured packages it tells this:

```
C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60
          packages = body.filter(function(pack) {

                          ^

TypeError: body.filter is not a function
    at C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\featured.js:60:27
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UPV\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
```

I tried to install the `x32-bit` version but with any good results.

Answer (score 0):

[Atom](https://github.com/atom) was discontinued and archived, I think that's why you can't install packages, if you have problems you can use [Pulsar editor](https://pulsar-edit.dev/), the successor of Atom.